How to restrict read access to file in S3 file
I'm new in AWS S3. My project needs to upload images to a 'private' S3 bucket (disable all public access setting in S3) and allows only certain users to access these images who have valid JWT token (mostly stored in browser, maybe localStorage / cookie)
So how can I setup S3 service and implement in C# to archive this goal: open URL with valid token then user can view image, and show unauthorize access page if user don't valid token. Sample content may be like below
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>
<Message>The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:4087a246-001e-0002-3481-37acce000000 Time:2024-11-15T17:13:52.7976811Z</Message>
</Error>

These 2 examples are tested with same signed url
I found something like cloudfront but I don't know where I need to start or is that my expected stuff
Thanks

That's not how S3 permissions work, permissions are allocated to user accounta. It will be up tp your code to validate the token, and if it's correct then use an appropriate account to serve the  image back to the user.

but I don't know how to implement it in backend when user loads the image from s3 because the image comes from other domain (amazon)

We can use CloudFront distributions to secure the S3 object
Here's step by step guide
The term I mentioned above about the valid token can be checked by trigger a lambda function when accessing to a signed url
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-signed-urls-using-lambda-secretsmanager

Amazon S3 buckets are private by default. Therefore, your first requirement is already met.
To provide access to specific people, you have a couple of choices:
Option 1: AWS Credentials
You can create IAM Users and request Security Credentials. This is typically used for programmatic access. When accessing the file in S3, you can provide the credentials and gain access to the private file.
Option 2: Pre-signed URL
Alternatively, your C# program can use IAM credentials to generate an Amazon S3 pre-signed URL, which provides time-limited access to private objects in Amazon S3. The users can simply use this URL in their browser to access the file as normal.
It would be the responsibility of your C# program to authenticate the users and verify that they should be entitled access to the file. If they are permitted, the program can generate the pre-signed URL in a few lines of code.

option 2 may be good but if a presign Url is generated, then everyone without token can view this image (incognito mode for eg). My goal needs to return image if at least user has a token (nevermind if token is valid or not, that is the minimum condition)

Yes, anyone who has the pre-signed URL can access the image. The typical pattern is to verify that the user is authorized to access the image and then generate a time-limited pre-signed URL (eg for 5 minutes). This should prevent the pre-signed URL from 'leaking' to other users.

that solution I applied with azure storage service using SAS token. it has same behavior with your option 2. that's why I switch to aws s3 to get more advance benifits from it. I don't want to do the same behavior like azure which I did before

I added an answer below. I think this resolves my issue
